# How to remove reply link?

Tags: comments

I've installed the [AJAX Comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) module in my Drupal site.

Am unable to find the configuration to remove the **reply** Link from the comment reply, kindly suggest.

Attaching a screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement [template_preprocess_comment()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/7.x) in your module file or theme's template.php file. And check if comment has Parent Comment ID (pid), if yes then remove reply link.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_comment().
 */
function [MODULE/THEME_NAME]_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  $comment = $variables['elements']['#comment'];
  if (!empty($comment->pid)) {
    unset($variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']);
  }
}
```

Comment: vote up . this is good solution

Comment: it is not working for me.

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you try clearing cache after implementing above hook?

Comment: sorry i forgot to clear the cahce.it's working perfectly fine.and one more thing is it possible to we can use this same hook to hide some field values in indented comments right?

Comment: Yes, we can. You can also use this hook to add new fields to show in comment, but for that you'll need to override comment template file (.tpl.php) and print new variable.

Comment: @Yogesh can i know how to alter comment reply form. without affect new comment form.

Comment: You can use hook_form_alter and use same condition like above.

Comment: one more doubt,i was added **mytheme_form_comment_form_alter** in template.php but it is not working.